# Storing Button Pressed In Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have collection view where you can select 4 buttons, it is like a quiz with A, B, C, D. I need to store which one they clicked before they go to the next question (They will swipe to go to the next question since it is a collection view) The controller looks like this: [image]

First: Essentially the code used to display the image above, I have created a database which is parsed using this:

```
struct Question {
    let fact: String
    let question: String
    let answers: [String: String]
    let correctAnswer: String
    let revenue: String

    init?(with dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        guard let fact = dictionary["fact"] as? String,
            let question = dictionary["question"] as? String,
            let answerA = dictionary["answer_a"] as? String,
            let answerB = dictionary["answer_b"] as? String,
            let answerC = dictionary["answer_c"] as? String,
            let answerD = dictionary["answer_d"] as? String,
            let revenue = dictionary["revenue"] as? String,
            let correctAnswer = dictionary["correctAnswer"] as? String else { return nil }

        self.fact = fact
        self.question = question
        self.revenue = revenue
        var answersDict = [String: String]()

        answersDict["answer_a"] = answerA
        answersDict["answer_b"] = answerB
        answersDict["answer_c"] = answerC
        answersDict["answer_d"] = answerD

        self.answers = answersDict
        self.correctAnswer = correctAnswer

    }
```

Second: Then I display using this code:

```
extension QuestionCell {
func configure(with model: Question) {
    factLabel.text = model.fact
    questionLabel.text = model.question
    revenueLabel.text = model.revenue

    let views = answersStack.arrangedSubviews
    for view in views {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    for (id, answer) in model.answers {
        print(index)
        print(id)
        let answerLabel = UILabel()
        answerLabel.text = answer

        answersStack.addArrangedSubview(answerLabel)

        let answerButton = UIButton()
        let imageNormal = UIImage(named: "circle_empty")
        answerButton.setImage(imageNormal, for: .normal)
        let imageSelected = UIImage(named: "circle_filled")
        answerButton.setImage(imageSelected, for: .selected)
        answerButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        answerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(answerPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        answersStack.addArrangedSubview(answerButton)

    }
}
}
```

Is there a way to store the button I clicked? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this: There is an obvious problem with this, and that is that this will not work with a collection view, because you only 4 buttons for the entire quiz not for every view controller. Could you describe that a bit more?

Comment: Since I have a collection it means that you swipe between many controllers, and those 4 buttons will be there for every controller. The method that is used to create an action for every button will not work, because I only have 4 buttons. Does this make sense?

Comment: But when you swipe to a new set of questions, I assume you save the answers and load the new questions/answer set. when you create your `answerButton` could you just add `answerButton.tag = index + 100`? Then in `answerPressed` pull the tag which would tell you the answer  that was selected.

Comment: My solution does not suggest that you create an `IBAction` for every button. It suggests you reuse the same `IBAction` for all the buttons and determine which button was pressed by examining the `sender.tag`.

Comment: I can't use the IBAction one button method because there are no buttons it is just a blank stack view and all the button are created inside my code. Do you have a different solution?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't have to be an `IBAction`. It can be any button target. In your case it's `answerPressed`

Comment: Could you just update your code so it would work with button target, that would be great

Answer (score 0):

**Well there is one sure shot way out of this situation.**

1. Make a custom cell for the collectionView.
2. Add button outlets and action the the customCell's class
3. Create and make use of delegate methods in customCell's class and when implementing the customCell in your ViewController set the delegate to
   self.
4. Trigger the delegate methods when button actions are done (inside your custom cell).
5. Provide your customCell the current indexpath when using it in cellForItemAt method.
6. Make use of that indexPath to decide which button was triggered.

**You should be thinking something close to this approach for a robust solution.**

Answer (score 0):

The way I've handled this in the past is to use the tag on a `UIButton` and just keep track of which tag is currently selected. With this approach I can use the same `IBAction` for every button and all I need to do is pull the tag from the `sender` in the function body. While maybe not as flexible and robust is an approach using subclassing, it's a bit quicker to implement.

First set your tags when you create your buttons (I use 100-104 to avoid conflicts with other buttons).  Since you're creating your buttons in a CollectionView, you'll need to set the tag in your `configure()` function:

```
func configure(with model: Question) {
    ...
    for (id, answer) in model.answers {
        ...
        answerButton.setImage(imageSelected, for: .selected)
        answerButton.tag = index
        answerButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        answerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(answerPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

Create an instance variable:

```
var selectedAnswerIndex = -1
```

Then assign this IBAction to each of you buttons:

```
func answerPressed(_ sender: UIButton){

    selectedAnswerIndex = sender.tag
    hilightNewOne(sender: sender)
}
```

Comment: The thing is there is no one button. It is just in something called an answer stack. I set the A,B,C,D in the code

Comment: Thanks for the edit but since it is collection view it will not know the index of which collection view it is on. Is there way to make that work as well?

Comment: Also, what is hilightNewOne?

Comment: I think I've given you everything you need to implement a solution. `hilightNewOne()` is from your code.

Comment: Sorry I think you don't understand hilightNewOne is from my old code, that is the one where I tell you what I tried but won't work for a collection view

Comment: I updated the code. Sorry if this was confusing, but this is the code I am using.

Comment: I would need the code of the viewcontroller that calls your QuestionCell.configure

Comment: So you mean the struct, where all the data is stored?